# JavaScript '\n' madness

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace, newline

I'm trying to convert a string like `'Some\nexample\nstring'` into an array like `['Some', '\n', 'example', '\n', 'string']`

But it's insane that I have to do this:

```
    let words = text.replace('\n', ' \\n ').split(/\s/);
    words = words.map(it => {
      if (it === '\\n') return '\n'
      else return it
    })
    // result: ['Some', '\n', 'example', '\n', 'string']
```

Because this doesn't work:

```
    const words = text.replace('\n', ' \n ').split(/\s/);
    // result: ['Some', '', '', 'example', 'string']
```

Nor this:

```
    const words = text.replace('\n', ' \\n ').split(/\s/);
    // result: ['Some', '\\n', 'example', 'string']
```

Nor this:

```
    const words = text.replace('\n', ' \\\n ').split(/\s/);
    // result: ['Some', '\\', '', 'example', 'string']
```

What gives?

Comment: You are splitting by whitespace (`\s`), which includes the newline character. If you want to only split by spaces, maybe just use `.split(" ")`

Comment: it's funny, you concentrated on the replace, and not once changed the split :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the split pattern to be included in the result, capture it, e.g.

```js
console.log(
  'Some\nexample\nstring'.split(/(\n)/)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a string `match` approach.  We can alternatively match groups of whitespace or non whitespace characters.

```js
var input = 'Some\nexample\nstring';
var parts = input.match(/\s+|\S+/g);
console.log(parts);
```